# Thrift Tserializer and TJSONProtocol

Tags: python, java, c++, erlang, thrift

I have a question about the Tserializer and the TJSONProtocol offered by Thrift.
I use Thrift to implement a RPC between server and client written in different programming languages. I need to add new functionality in my system implementing an integrity check on the data exchanged between client and server.

The idea is to convert in string the data exchanged between sender and receiver (defined in the IDL thrift) and use this string as an input to the algorithm for the integrity calculation.
For structured data types, I want to leverage on the Tserializer based on TJSONProtocol to obtain a JSON string (representing the data to protect) to provide as input to the algorithm for integrity calculation.

Is it correct to assume that the JSON string resulting from conversion is always the same (assuming to have the same input data) across different programming languages?
I mean, can I assume that the behaviour of TSerializer (based on TJSONProtocol) is the same across the different implementations of Thrift libraries available for the different programming languages?

Comment: Isn't that kind of the point of Thrift?

Answer (score 0):

**TL,DR: No.**

There are several factors that are not guaranteed. Just as one example, the order of `list<>` is preserved and guarateed, but this is not the case for `set<>` or `map<>` containers. Hence, even though the data before serialization and after deserialization are the same, the serialized data may differ just because of implementation differences.